# Ejecutar función JavaScript para comparar inputs

Tags: javascript, html

¿Hola gente como están? estoy intentando hacer algo muy sencillo como habilitar/desabilitar un campo con js, pero no me sale, que estoy haciendo mal? seguí todos los pasos de este tutorial:

[tutorial habilitar/desabilitar campos con javascript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cChuvfRRcYY&t=216s)

este es mi codigo (el mismo del video)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>prueba</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function habilitar()

    {

        var camp1= document.getElementById('valor1');
        var camp2= document.getElementById('valor2');
        var boton= document.getElementById('boton');

        if (camp1.value != camp2.value) {

            boton.disabled = true;
        }else {
            boton.disabled = false;
        }
    }



</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>


<input type="number"  id="valor1" >
<input type="number" id="valor2">
<input type="button"  id="boton" value="boton">



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

pero miren como se me ve en mi editor:

[image: codigo en sublime text]

como veran el "camp1.value" no se cambia de color por lo que creo que no se esta tomando correcatmente... .saben que puede ser? gracias

Comment: No estas haciendo llamado a la funcion habilitar() en ningun momento!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falto completar el tutorial, donde claramente se muestra que hay que mandar llamar la función en el segundo input a través del evento `onKeyUp`, así mira

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>prueba</title>


</head>
<body>
<form>


<input type="password"  id="valor1" >
<input type="password" id="valor2" onKeyUp="habilitar()">
<input type="button"  id="boton" value="boton" >



</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function habilitar()

    {

        var camp1= document.getElementById('valor1');
        var camp2= document.getElementById('valor2');
        var boton= document.getElementById('boton');

        if (camp1.value != camp2.value) {

            boton.disabled = true;
        }else {
            boton.disabled = false;
        }
    }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Como notas se manda llamar a la función, la ultima observación
>   incluido para el autor del video los códigos JS por optimización deben
>   ir como los coloque antes de que cierre la etiqueta body  y no al
>   inicio

Comment: muchas gracias! jaja de ansioso pense que ya no funcionaba... anda perfecto... lo que si me gustaria que cambiara de color el ".value" cuando estoy en js me ayuda a orientarme, como lo configuro? gracias!

Comment: abre otra pregunta bien explicada y con muestra del código intentado y con gusto se te apoya, recuerda para que las preguntas sean bien recibidas no solo es la pregunta si no un avance del código que trataste @mariano1424